# Flash Builder debugger failed to connect to the running application with tomcat

Tags: actionscript-3, tomcat, apache-flex, remote-debugging, flash-builder4.5

I had look into similar question in the stack overflow and tried all the solutions given there, but nothing works for me.

I have a Flex Web application running in localhost with tomcat, i have used Mongrel plugin in Flash Builder to run tomcat.

I am using Firefox browser.

When I try to debug my application it is throwing below error :

> The Flash Builder debugger failed to connect to the running
>   application.
>
> Ensure that:
>
> 1. For in-browser applications, you are running the debugger version of Flash Player.
> 2. For network debugging on a mobile device, you have a reliable network connection to the device, and port 7935 is open on your
>      machine's firewall.
>        Device connection help

[link : error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzDcp.png)

[image]

I did check with netstat for port 7935  and there is no service running on this port.

I also added the solutions in catalina.properties file as suggested by others in related question but it did not worked out.

kindly help me fix this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not debugging a mobile device, so the second option can be disregarded. Have you installed the flash debugger for Firefox from: https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html ?

Comment: @RobinvandenBogaard, Yes i have a flash debugger player installed. I have one other project which is a simple flex project and it is working fine while debugging.

Comment: Ok, too bad that was the easy solution. Now it will be a bit harder to find the specific problem because we have no idea how your project and development environment is setup. There are quite a few posibilities ;) How are you starting the tomcat server and how are you trying to debug the flex application, what steps do you take in Flashbuilder. When you try to debug the flex application does it open Firefox at all? What URL?

Comment: @RobinvandenBogaard, I am using Mongrel plugin in Flash Builder to run tomcat. Using Flash Builder Debug profile to debug application and in debug configuration i have given URL to http://localhost:8080/myapplication/index.html?Authorised=true&debug=true.   I am running application in Firefox browser, While debuggin application gets open in firefox but the progress bar of debugger gets stuck at 57% and after sometime it throws error.

Answer (score 0):

The tomcat application is probably not serving the debuggable swf from flashbuilder project. What I have in a (I believe) similar setup is: also change the output directory from your flex project to the webcontent folder of the tomcat application.

Flashbuilder generally doesn't create index.html from the template but ${project.name}.html instead. Make sure you use that when trying to debug.

```
{workspace}/flexapp/src/MyApplication.mxml
{workspace}/webapp/WebContent/bin-debug      <-- oupput folder of flexapp
```

If you start the tomcat application from Flashbuilder now it will include the debuggable SWF from the flex project.

The flex output URL should then point to http://localhost:8080/myapplication/bind-debug/MyApplication.html?Authorised=true&debug=true

Comment: As per your suggestion i should change the output folder under flex build Path from default "bin-debug" to webapps folder of tomcat. Is my understanding is correct?

Comment: I changed it to the tomcat project webcontent folder. Including the bin-debug folder. This means I changed the output url from flex project as well to match the bin-debug folder url. This way for source control I can simply ignore that folder.

Comment: I have done that changes but flex builder still showing the above error while debugging. Path for my bin-debug is C:\Tomcat\webapps\myprojectname and i have given the same path in Output folder for flex project under properties flex Build Path

Comment: I mean the tomcat project in flashbuilder. So it will treat the output of the flex project as static webcontent in the tomcat project.